# Como hacer una Subconsulta en SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

Tengo en mi BD dos tablas una llamada comments y la otra llamada users.

En la tabla comments tengo las siguientes columnas:
id_comment
id_speaker
id_user

En la tabla users tengo las siguientes columnas:

id_user
name
codigo

Lo que quiero hacer es mostrar en una consulta  el id_comment, id_speaker(este id se obtiene de la tabla users), id_user(este id se obtiene de la tabla users). En id_speaker y id_user quiero mostrar el nombre de la persona en lugar de solo un numero.

Estoy haciendo la siguiente consulta:

```
    SELECT comments.id_comment, users.name AS usuario, comments.id_speaker AS ponente, comments.comment 
    FROM comments 
    INNER JOIN users ON comments.id_user = users.id_user
```

Me muestra correctamente todo, solo que en id_speaker me muestra el id, lo que quiero hacer es que me muestre el nombre, pero la tabla users muestra todos los usuarios es decir los ponentes y usuarios normales y para diferenciarlo es la columna código de la tabla users, si código es 3 entonces es ponente si es 2 es usuario normal.
Saben como podría solucionarlo? espero se entienda mi explicación

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Tendrás que usar "WHERE" seguido de unos paréntesis y hacer una consulta con el SELECT de nuevo

Te pongo la referencia a las webs aquí:

https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_where.asp

https://desarrolloweb.com/articulos/2337.php

Comment: Disclaimer: Yo no voté negativamente esta respuesta. Dicho esto, es la única que responde a la pregunta de OP: "Cómo hacer una sub-consulta".

Comment: Gracias por la aportación sirvió de mucho para entender mejor el problema.

Answer (score 3):

Tienes que repetir el join con la tabla users

```
 SELECT comments.id_comment, usuarios.name AS usuario, ponentes.name AS ponente, comments.comment 
    FROM comments 
    INNER JOIN users usuarios ON comments.id_user = usuarios.id_user
    INNER JOIN users ponentes ON comments.id_user = ponentes.id_speaker
```

Si quieres puedes filtrar las tablas de usuarios por el tipo correspondiente:

```
 SELECT comments.id_comment, usuarios.name AS usuario, ponentes.name AS ponente, comments.comment 
    FROM comments 
    INNER JOIN users usuarios ON comments.id_user = usuarios.id_user
    INNER JOIN users ponentes ON comments.id_user = ponentes.id_speaker
WHERE users.codigo=3 and ponentes.codigo=2
```

Comment: Gracias, fue de mucha ayuda, utilice la primer consulta, pero cambie :  INNER JOIN users ponentes ON comments.id_user = ponentes.id_speaker por  INNER JOIN users ponentes ON comments.id_speaker = ponentes.id_user. Gracias

Answer (score 0):

SELECT comments.id_comment, users.name AS usuario, comments.id_speaker
FROM comments JOIN users ON comments.id_user = users.id_user;

Comment: Tal y como está redactada, tu respuesta no es clara. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir detalles adicionales que ayuden a los demás a entender cómo esto responde a la pregunta formulada. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).